# Expressão não retorna o resultado desejado quando o dado é captado pelo input

Tags: javascript

Fiz uma expressão para calcular juros compostos com aporte mensal, com base [Nesse site](https://fazaconta.com/valor-futuro-investimentos.htm)
A expressão ficou assim:

```js
function jurosCompostosComAporte(p,m,i,n){
  let valorFuturo,
      valorPresente=p,
      mensalidade=m,
      periodo=n,
      taxa=i;
  
      valorFuturo =  valorPresente * Math.pow( 1 + taxa , periodo ) +
      mensalidade * ((Math.pow( 1 + taxa , periodo ) - 1) / taxa);

      return valorFuturo.toFixed(2);

}

console.log(jurosCompostosComAporte(100,10,0.030,12)); 
//Valor inicial 100 com 10 depositados mensalmente: rendimento de 3% durante 12 meses.
```

Tudo funciona como o esperado, até ao inserir os valores com `input`'s via DOM.

Ao inserir a taxa por um `input` de número, ela retorna resultados bem maiores do que o esperado, como `1.969946535161522e+25` (Testei a mesma taxa de 0.030 = 3% no `input` e inserindo via código, no código retornou `36.46`).

Gostaria de saber porque isso acontece, pois quando insiro a taxa sem tirar do `input`, tudo ocorre sem erros.

Aqui a função que eu puxo a taxa do `input`:

```js
function calculateResults(valorInicialID, valorMensalID ,taxaID,tempoId){
    var valorInicial = document.getElementById(valorInicialID).value;
    var valorMensal = document.getElementById(valorMensalID).value;
    var taxaCustomizada = document.getElementById(taxaID).value;
    var tempo = document.getElementById(tempoId).value;

    document.getElementById('poupanca').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,0.0040,tempo);
    document.getElementById('rendafixa').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,0.0050,tempo);
    document.getElementById('tesourodireto').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,0.0070,tempo);
    document.getElementById('carteiraalunos').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,0.030,tempo);
    document.getElementById('seujuroscustomizado').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,taxaCustomizada,tempo);
```

```html
 Valor inicial: <input type="number" id="valorinicial"><br>
    Aporte mensal: <input type="number" id="valormensal"><br>
    Taxa: <input type="number" id="taxacustomizada"><br>
    Tempo: <input type="number" id="tempo"> 
    <select  id="seletorTempo">
        <option value="0">Meses</option>
        <option value="1">Anos</option>
    </select><br>
    <div id="chart-container"></div>

    <a href="#" onclick="calculateResults('valorinicial','valormensal','taxacustomizada', 'tempo')">Ativar</a>

    <p id="poupanca"></p>
    <p id="rendafixa"></p>
    <p id="tesourodireto"></p>
    <p id="carteiraalunos"></p>
    <p id="seujuroscustomizado"></p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o `value` de um elemento é [sempre uma string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties). Então quando você passa o `document.getElementById(...).value`, a função `jurosCompostosComAporte` está recebendo uma string.

E quando você passa a taxa como uma string, ao somar `1` o resultado não é bem o que você espera:

```js
console.log(1 + 0.03); // 1.03
console.log(1 + '0.03'); // 10.03
```

Veja que no segundo caso foi feita uma concatenação com a string, resultando em `10.03`. Em seguida, `Math.pow` converterá isso para número, e o resultado será 10.03 - e não 1.03 - elevado ao período.

A solução é converter os valores para números. Como os valores inicial e mensal, assim como a taxa, podem ter casas decimais, use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) para converter a string para um número. Já para o período, entendo que só podem ser valores inteiros, então use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (a menos que você queira calcular `2.7` meses, aí use `parseFloat`).

Além disso, a função `jurosCompostosComAporte` já poderia receber as variáveis com os nomes corretos (e também mais significativos), e a exponenciação poderia ser feita apenas uma vez:

```js
function jurosCompostosComAporte(valorPresente, mensalidade, taxa, periodo){
    let t = Math.pow(1 + taxa, periodo); // calcula uma vez só
    let valorFuturo = valorPresente * t + mensalidade * ((t - 1) / taxa);

    return valorFuturo.toFixed(2);
}

function calculateResults(valorInicialID, valorMensalID ,taxaID,tempoId){
    let valorInicial = parseFloat(document.getElementById(valorInicialID).value);
    let valorMensal = parseFloat(document.getElementById(valorMensalID).value);
    let taxaCustomizada = parseFloat(document.getElementById(taxaID).value);
    let tempo = parseInt(document.getElementById(tempoId).value);

    document.getElementById('poupanca').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,0.0040,tempo);
    document.getElementById('rendafixa').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,0.0050,tempo);
    document.getElementById('tesourodireto').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,0.0070,tempo);
    document.getElementById('carteiraalunos').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,0.030,tempo);
    document.getElementById('seujuroscustomizado').innerHTML = jurosCompostosComAporte(valorInicial,valorMensal,taxaCustomizada,tempo);
}
```

```html
 Valor inicial: <input type="number" id="valorinicial"><br>
    Aporte mensal: <input type="number" id="valormensal"><br>
    Taxa: <input type="number" id="taxacustomizada"><br>
    Tempo: <input type="number" id="tempo"> 
    <select  id="seletorTempo">
        <option value="0">Meses</option>
        <option value="1">Anos</option>
    </select><br>
    <div id="chart-container"></div>

    <a href="#" onclick="calculateResults('valorinicial','valormensal','taxacustomizada', 'tempo')">Ativar</a>

    <p id="poupanca"></p>
    <p id="rendafixa"></p>
    <p id="tesourodireto"></p>
    <p id="carteiraalunos"></p>
    <p id="seujuroscustomizado"></p>
```

---

Lembrando ainda que [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) pode arredondar o valor, mas há outras formas de arredondar ou não o número:

```js
function arredonda(valor) {
    return Math.round(valor * 100) / 100;
}

function naoArredonda(valor) {
    return Math.floor(valor * 100) / 100;
}

[1.478, 1.472].forEach(n =>
  console.log(`${n} => ${arredonda(n)}, ${naoArredonda(n)}, ${n.toFixed(2)}`));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Pensei que o valor já estava em número, pois o tipo do campo em HTML era number, e ao debugar no console. Os números apareciam sem aspas (Que geralmente aparecem nas strings). Agora tudo está Ok. Obrigado também pelos toques na sintaxe e otimizações do código!

Comment: @Lucas Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.